# Keep vertical Text inside container

Tags: html, css

I am currently trying to create some cards with some details about players. The name of the players is displayed vertically to the card, which I have positioned `absolutely`. The problem is that as the name gets longer, the name then spreads down instead of going flush from bottom to top. I've tried couple of solution but i can't get it work. Is this even possible? Or does the `transform` value here just cause problems?

What i'm trying to achieved is that:

[image]

```css
.potw-section{
    background-color: #111;
}

.container{
   width: 100%;
    max-width: 1260px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 1.875rem;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.potw-grid{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: auto;
    gap: 0px 90px;
}

.potw-card{
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    align-items: center;
}

.potw-meta{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 1.563rem;
    line-height: 29px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 700;
    width: 95px;
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(17, 17, 17, 0.7) 62.11%, rgba(17, 17, 17, 0.5) 62.11%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 122.11%);
}

.potw-meta-inner{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 1.25rem 0; 
}

.potw-value{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 1.563rem;
    line-height: 29px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 700;
    margin-bottom: 1.25rem;
}

.potw-value img{
    max-height: 30px;
}

.potw-outline{
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-text-stroke-width: 1px;
  -webkit-text-stroke-color: #fff;
    font-size: 2.188rem;
    line-height: 39px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 700;
    left: -46%;
    bottom: 27%;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    transform: rotate(270deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="potw-section">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="potw-grid">
            <div class="potw-card">
                <p class="potw-outline">Malte Delow</p>
                <div class="potw-meta">
                    <div class="potw-meta-inner">
                        <div class="potw-value">
                            <span>PPG</span>
                            <span>28</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="potw-value">
                            <span>PPG</span>
                            <span>28</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="potw-value">
                            <span>PPG</span>
                            <span>28</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="potw-value">
                            <img src="https://i.ibb.co/KWgnKvh/lakers.png" >
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <img src="https://i.ibb.co/NFxXnZm/potw-player.png">
            </div>
            <div class="potw-card">
                <p class="potw-outline">Malte Delow</p>
                <div class="potw-meta">
                    <div class="potw-meta-inner">
                        <div class="potw-value">
                            <span>PPG</span>
                            <span>28</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="potw-value">
                            <span>PPG</span>
                            <span>28</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="potw-value">
                            <span>PPG</span>
                            <span>28</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="potw-value">
                            <img src="https://i.ibb.co/KWgnKvh/lakers.png" >
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <img src="https://i.ibb.co/NFxXnZm/potw-player.png">
            </div>
            <div class="potw-card">
                <p class="potw-outline">Longer Name Delow</p>
                <div class="potw-meta">
                    <div class="potw-meta-inner">
                        <div class="potw-value">
                            <span>PPG</span>
                            <span>28</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="potw-value">
                            <span>PPG</span>
                            <span>28</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="potw-value">
                            <span>PPG</span>
                            <span>28</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="potw-value">
                            <img src="https://i.ibb.co/KWgnKvh/lakers.png" >
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <img src="https://i.ibb.co/NFxXnZm/potw-player.png">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the options to use `transform-origin` for `potw-outline`

```css
.potw-section{
    background-color: #111;
}

.container{
   width: 100%;
    max-width: 1260px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 1.875rem;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.potw-grid{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: auto;
    gap: 0px 90px;
}

.potw-card{
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    align-items: center;
}

.potw-meta{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 1.563rem;
    line-height: 29px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 700;
    width: 95px;
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(17, 17, 17, 0.7) 62.11%, rgba(17, 17, 17, 0.5) 62.11%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 122.11%);
}

.potw-meta-inner{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 1.25rem 0; 
}

.potw-value{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 1.563rem;
    line-height: 29px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 700;
    margin-bottom: 1.25rem;
}

.potw-value img{
    max-height: 30px;
}

.potw-outline{
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-text-stroke-width: 1px;
  -webkit-text-stroke-color: #fff;
    font-size: 2.188rem;
    line-height: 39px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 700;
    bottom:0;
    left:10%;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    transform: rotate(270deg);
    transform-origin:0 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="potw-section">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="potw-grid">
            <div class="potw-card">
                <p class="potw-outline">Malte Delow</p>
                <div class="potw-meta">
                    <div class="potw-meta-inner">
                        <div class="potw-value">
                            <span>PPG</span>
                            <span>28</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="potw-value">
                            <span>PPG</span>
                            <span>28</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="potw-value">
                            <span>PPG</span>
                            <span>28</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="potw-value">
                            <img src="https://i.ibb.co/KWgnKvh/lakers.png" >
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <img src="https://i.ibb.co/NFxXnZm/potw-player.png">
            </div>
            <div class="potw-card">
                <p class="potw-outline">Malte Delow</p>
                <div class="potw-meta">
                    <div class="potw-meta-inner">
                        <div class="potw-value">
                            <span>PPG</span>
                            <span>28</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="potw-value">
                            <span>PPG</span>
                            <span>28</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="potw-value">
                            <span>PPG</span>
                            <span>28</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="potw-value">
                            <img src="https://i.ibb.co/KWgnKvh/lakers.png" >
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <img src="https://i.ibb.co/NFxXnZm/potw-player.png">
            </div>
            <div class="potw-card">
                <p class="potw-outline">Longer Name Delow</p>
                <div class="potw-meta">
                    <div class="potw-meta-inner">
                        <div class="potw-value">
                            <span>PPG</span>
                            <span>28</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="potw-value">
                            <span>PPG</span>
                            <span>28</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="potw-value">
                            <span>PPG</span>
                            <span>28</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="potw-value">
                            <img src="https://i.ibb.co/KWgnKvh/lakers.png" >
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <img src="https://i.ibb.co/NFxXnZm/potw-player.png">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You saved me hours. Thank you.